# Getting list of likers for an instagram post - Python

Tags: python, instagram

How I can get list of users who liked post on Instagram using Python?
I was using Instaloader and Selenium, but Instaloader very slowly and Selenium don’t work correctly.

Comment: Please show the code you were trying to use. Maybe we can pinpoint why it was not working correctly. Also share your error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium is actually perfect for that job. I did something similar long ago

also, if you need some directions, this video covers it very thoroughly:

[instagram selenium bot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2GBO_QjRlo)

Comment: Exactly that is what I was wondering. I also made a bot using selenium which messages people if the likes on their latest post is above a given value. Of course that was long ago and insta has changed but it should be possible.

Comment: But it works slowly when the post has a lot of likes